# Can't reliably detect scroll bottom between iPhone portrait and landscape modes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, scroll, detect

I'm trying to detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of the document. My current solution works fine in desktop browsers, and with Mobile Safari in landscape mode (with a 1px variance that I can't yet explain). However, I'm getting a completely different result for Mobile Safari in landscape mode.

I have a working example here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5634676/checkbottom.html

The detection routine boils down to:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height())) {
  // Bottom reached
}
```

Can you explain the difference between the two modes and help me reliably detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the document?

**Update**

I've updated the linked example fixing the bug pointed out by theflyingbrush. The results for landscape and portrait modes are now closer together (but there is still an as yet unexplained variance of 52px). Importantly though, for both portrait and landscape modes scrolling to the bottom of the page is still not detected.

Comment: +1: I had a similar issue when developing a site for mobile. Never found out the reason. My fix was to increase the detection area for when the user was near the bottom. Upvoted.

Comment: What actual devices are you testing on? The issue may have to do with differences between non-Retina and Retina displays.

Comment: I'm only testing on an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on IOS mobile devices. Replace 'document' with 'body' fixed my issue.

```js
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('body').height() - 200 )
```

Also, it is better to check if 'near' bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The height of the window changes when the device orientation changes, invalidating your windowHeight var stored on doc ready. Update it by listening for the orientationchange event and recalculating the window height. Something like:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", change);

function change(){
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
}
```

**Edit**: Confusing this, because it also involves the viewport scale. Here's a link to a working version: http://appunit.co.uk/scroll

You need to account for the height of the address bar in your calculations, because $(window).scrollTop() returns 0 until the address bar is scrolled offscreen. So, add the address bar height (60px) to scrollTop to get the distance scrolled. This is made more complicated if you haven't set a viewport meta tag in your html specifying width=device-width. In that case the viewport will be scaled from 320x356 to 980x1091, and the amount of virtual height the address bar takes up is scaled also. Summary:

```
var scaleFactor = ($(window).height()/356).toPrecision(2);
// toPrecision(2) prevents rounding error..
var addressBarHeight = 60 * scaleFactor;

// and when calculating scrollTop
var scrollTop = addressBarHeight + $(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. It was important to fix, but the problem persists as I've detailed in my update above.